# transform children to same position as if their parent was transformed?

Tags: html, css, transform

Here is a picture of two paragraphs:

[image: two paragraphs]

When I mouse over the top paragraph, I scale up the text.

[image: enlarged top paragraph]

When I mouse over the bottom paragraph, I only want the spans I've tagged with an orange background to scale up.

[image: enlarged bottom paragraph]

But *notice how the orange words overlap each other*.  **How do I get the spans to scale so that they appear in the same positions as they do when the whole paragraph is scaled?**

Here is a demo http://jsbin.com/yamatuke/1

And here is the structure of the html:

```
<div id="a" class="textblock">
Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet esse minim anim, ham pig dolore bacon. Laboris anim drumstick boudin, eiusmod shankle minim ground round jowl nulla fatback consectetur magna aliquip brisket. Culpa ground round ullamco officia. In voluptate pariatur bacon.
</div>


<div id="b" class="textblock">
<span>Bacon&nbsp;</span><span>ipsum&nbsp;</span><span>dolor&nbsp;</span><span>sit&nbsp;</span><span>amet&nbsp;</span><span>esse&nbsp;</span><span>minim&nbsp;</span><span>anim,&nbsp;</span><span>ham&nbsp;</span><span>pig dolore&nbsp;</span><span>bacon.&nbsp;</span><span>Laboris&nbsp;</span><span>anim&nbsp;</span><span>drumstick&nbsp;</span><span>boudin,&nbsp;</span><span>eiusmod&nbsp;</span><span>shankle&nbsp;</span><span>minim&nbsp;</span><span>ground&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>round&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>jowl&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>nulla&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>fatback&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>consectetur&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>magna&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>aliquip&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>brisket.&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>Culpa&nbsp;</span><span class='c'>ground&nbsp;</span><span>round&nbsp;</span><span>ullamco&nbsp;</span><span>officia.&nbsp;</span><span>In&nbsp;</span><span>voluptate&nbsp;</span><span>pariatur&nbsp;</span><span>bacon.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: try span {display:inline;}

Comment: @IsaacRajaei Making that change converts the desired flow of a paragraph into a long line of text http://jsbin.com/yamatuke/5/

Answer (score 0):

The `<span></span>` tags still inherit the attributes of the *line* they are a part of. In other words they are horizontally centered in the same way as the rest of the line. In order to achieve what you want you will have to change the *line-height* in your DIV to represent the size of the enlarged SPAN text.

Comment: there is an example try to make this

Comment: Wouldn't enlarging the line height only solve the vertical problem? Wouldn't the horizontal overlap persist?

Comment: @MrLister, horizontal overlapping shouldn't occur at all, unless he is not making the spans suddenly fixed or something. Overlapping occures due to the fact that the span size changed to more than the size of it container(line-height).

Comment: "container" may not be the right term here, but I think you get the point I was trying to make.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is the general idea?  http://jsbin.com/yamatuke/8/  If so, this does not work because -- the orange words still overlap and the paragraph does not have the same linespacing as the original paragraph.

Comment: @jedierikb You want to keep the line spacing, enlarge something within and not have it to overlap?

Comment: @Dropout: Yes, from the OP: How do I get the spans to scale so that they appear in the same positions as they do [would] when the whole paragraph is scaled?

Comment: @jedierikb That's not possible without creating a new element dynamically, which would have to *look out* for other zoomed elements. In other words, there's no simple solution for this. As I mentioned before - the SPAN still considers itself as a part of it's surrounding text, not a separate element, like DIV for example.